# How can I pass the optional parameter of a namedtuple in a function

Tags: python

```
__author__ = 'mayukhsarkar'
import collections


def search_student(database=None, ID=None):
    flag = False
    try:
        if ID is None or ID == 0:
            raise TypeError
        for each in database:
            if each.id == ID:
                print 'Student Name: ', each.name
                flag = True
    except TypeError:
        print 'Provide the arguments properly'
    finally:
        return flag


studentDatabase = collections.namedtuple("student", "id name roll_no phone email")

DATABASE = [studentDatabase(1, 'Mayukh Sarkar', 9, '555-2312', 'mayukh2012@hotmail,com'),
        studentDatabase(2, 'Alisha Sengupta', 7, '555-1345', 'alisha@gmail.com')]

if not search_student(DATABASE, 1):
    print "Data not found"
```

In this snippet I want a variable argument option in the function `search_student` so that if I pass the `roll_no`, `email` then if the student of that id is found then only roll & email will be printed along with name. But if I don't pass any argument, then only the name will be printed

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for. Here's an exercise that may help: Pretend that your function already behaves the way you want it to, and then post the code demonstrating how you *would* use it.

Comment: okay I am posing down please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use booleans to set the flag of whether to print the roll and email or not:

```
def search_student(database=None, ID=None, roll=False, email=False):
    if ID is None or ID == 0:
        print 'Provide the arguments properly'
        return False
    for each in database:
        if each.id == ID:
            print 'Student Name: {}'.format(each.name)
            if roll:
                print 'Stutent Roll: {}'.format(each.roll_no)
            if email:
                print("Student email: {}".format(each.email))
            break
    else:
        return "User does not exist in database"


studentDatabase = collections.namedtuple("student", "id name roll_no phone email")

DATABASE = [studentDatabase(1, 'Mayukh Sarkar', 9, '555-2312', 'mayukh2012@hotmail,com'),
            studentDatabase(2, 'Alisha Sengupta', 7, '555-1345', 'alisha@gmail.com')]
```

Output:

```
In [9]: search_student(DATABASE, 1, email=True,roll=True)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Stutent Roll: 9
Student email: mayukh2012@hotmail,com

In [10]: search_student(DATABASE, 1,roll=True)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Stutent Roll: 9

In [11]: search_student(DATABASE, 1, email=True)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Student email: mayukh2012@hotmail,com

In [12]: search_student(DATABASE, 1)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar

In [13]: search_student(DATABASE, 5)
Out[13]: 'User does not exist in database'
```

I would also store the users in a dict using the id as the key:

```
def search_student(database=None, ID=None, roll=False, email=False):
    if ID is None or ID == 0:
        print 'Provide the arguments properly'
        return False
    get = database.get(ID)
    if get is not None:
            print 'Student Name: {}'.format(get.name)
            if roll:
                print 'Student Roll: {}'.format(get.roll_no)
            if email:
                print("Student email: {}".format(get.email))
    else:
        return "User does not exist in database"
```

Then pass a dict as the database:

```
studentDatabase = collections.namedtuple("student", "id name roll_no phone email")

DATABASE = {1: studentDatabase(1, 'Mayukh Sarkar', 9, '555-2312', 'mayukh2012@hotmail,com'),
            2: studentDatabase(2, 'Alisha Sengupta', 7, '555-1345', 'alisha@gmail.com')}
```

The output is the same:

```
In [18]: search_student(DATABASE, 1, email=True,roll=True)Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Student Roll: 9
Student email: mayukh2012@hotmail,com

In [19]: search_student(DATABASE, 1,roll=True)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Student Roll: 9

In [20]: search_student(DATABASE, 1, email=True)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar
Student email: mayukh2012@hotmail,com

In [21]: search_student(DATABASE, 1)
Student Name: Mayukh Sarkar

In [22]: search_student(DATABASE, 5)
Out[22]: 'User does not exist in database'
```

You might be better off using a dict for all the logic but getattr will work with **kwargs:

```
import collections


def search_student(database=None, ID=None, **kwargs):
    if ID is None or ID == 0:
        print 'Provide the arguments properly'
        return False
    get = database.get(ID)
    if get is not None:
        print 'Student Name: {}'.format(get.name)
        for k in kwargs:
            print("Student {}: {}".format(k, getattr(get,k)))
    else:
        return "User does not exist in database"


studentDatabase = collections.namedtuple("student", "id name roll_no phone email")

DATABASE = {1: studentDatabase(1, 'Mayukh Sarkar', 9, '555-2312', 'mayukh2012@hotmail,com'),
            2: studentDatabase(2, 'Alisha Sengupta', 7, '555-1345', 'alisha@gmail.com')}

search_student(DATABASE,1,roll_no=True,email=True)
```

We need to catch when a user enters an invalid keyword/attribute, there are many ways to handle it but a simple way is to catch the attribute error:

```
        try:
            print("Student {}: {}".format(k, getattr(get, k)))
        except AttributeError:
            print("Informative message or whatever is suitable")
```

Or use hasattr and do whatever you want if it returns False:

```
 if get is not None:
    print 'Student Name: {}'.format(get.name)
    for k in kwargs:
        if not hasattr(get,k):
            continue
        print("Student {}: {}".format(k, getattr(get, k)))
```

Or pass a default value to getattr:

```
if get is not None:
        print 'Student Name: {}'.format(get.name)
        for k in kwargs:
            val = getattr(get, k,False)
            if val:
                print("Student {}: {}".format(k, val))
            else:....
```

Comment: That real handy but the problem is that every time I add some element to the named tuple I need to edit the whole function again... I wanted some method there all the optional parameters will be passed as a list and whatever we have in the list, for each element each. Listvalue will be printed

Comment: @MayukhSarkar,  you use **kwargs and use the exact same logic

Comment: But in that case I think I have to use dictionary not named tuple

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, the only problem you will have to catch is if a user enters a wrong keyword that is not a valid attribute. I will add an example of how to use kwargs

Comment: Yes you are right I think dictionary will be more efficient in this case

Comment: I have a dict example done, I will add that then add a kwargs version

Comment: That will be nice.. Thanks bro

Comment: That's a wonderful combination of dict and named tuple.. So the trick was to use dict... Thanks man

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, no worries, we have to catch when a user enters an attribute that does not exist as a keyword, I will add a try except version but there are many ways you can implement it, it all depends on how you want to go about it and what should happen

Comment: Try and catch would be nice.. Or else if we loop through each ID to check if the entered one exists or not,  then this process will be expensive for a large amount of data..

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, hasattr will also work, I added that too. It comes down to personal preference how you approach it and what you want to happen when the user enters incorrect data. The code above is just a push in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

so this is not the answer but a post because @Rob asked for further clarification

so if the function exists say `func(database=None, ID=None, [optionals])`

so when you call `func(DATABASE, 1, roll_no, email)`
name of the person whose ID is 1 & his/her email & roll will also be printed

but if I pass `func(DATABASE, 1, roll_no, email, phone)`
then name roll email & phone number will be printed but if I just give DATABASE & ID & no optionals, then only name should be printed..If no record is found with that ID, then it should not print anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `**` notation to pass variable amount of named arguments to your function.

If the argument is `**args` then, it would be a dictionary of any named arguments that are not already defined in the function definition , then you can check if `roll_no` or `email` is present in `args` if so, do your logic.

Example codes -

```
>>> def func(**args):
...     print(args)
...     if 'abc' in args:
...             print(args['abc'])
...
>>> func(hello=10)
{'hello': 10}
>>> func(hello=10,abc="Student")
{'hello': 10, 'abc': 'Student'}
Student
>>> def search_student(database=None, ID=None, **args):
...     if 'roll_no' in args:
...             print(args['roll_no'])
...
>>> search_student(roll_no=10)
10
```

Comment: I know this method be I think it cannot be extended for named tuple..You are talking about dictionary which I am not

Comment: I thought the requirement was to pass in an argument so as to determine if to print roll_no and email or not

Comment: no the requirement is not to just pass the variable arguments but pass them as a member of namedtuple