# Why should I ever use "getattr()"?

Tags: python

From my understanding, `getattr(object, "method")` is equivalent to `object.method()`. If this is true, what is the point of using `getattr`?

Comment: Your understanding is not quite correct, `getattr(object, "method")` is equivalent to `object.method` (no method call). You can of course call the method using `getattr` but that's spelled `getattr(object, "mehod")()`. This is inconsequential to your question though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089612/how-can-i-pass-the-optional-parameter-of-a-namedtuple-in-a-function/31089843#31089843

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in Python can have attributes.
For example you have an object `person`, that has several attributes: `name`, `gender`, etc.
You access these attributes (be it methods or data objects) usually writing: `person.name`, `person.gender`, `person.the_method()`, etc.

But what if you don't know the attribute's name at the time you write the program? For example you have attribute's name stored in a variable called `gender_attribute_name`.

if

```
attr_name = 'gender'
```

then, instead of writing

```
gender = person.gender
```

you can write

```
gender = getattr(person, attr_name)
```

Some practice:

```
>>> class Person():
...     name = 'Victor'
...     def say(self, what):
...         print(self.name, what)
... 
>>> getattr(Person, 'name')
'Victor'
>>> attr_name = 'name'
>>> person = Person()
>>> getattr(person, attr_name)
'Victor'
>>> getattr(person, 'say')('Hello')
Victor Hello
>>>
```

Comment: What you do here is assign the name of the attribute to attr_name once you know that 'name' is the correct name of the attribute?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getattr` if you have the name of the attribute as a string. e.g:

```
attribute = "some_attribute"
getattr(object, attribute)
```

Also it is nice to use when you have a default value that you want to use when the attribute is not set:

```
getattr(object, attribute, "default")  # does not raise AttributeError
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually when the name of the method is not known when you write the code:

```
def print_some_attr(obj, attr):
    print getattr(obj, attr)
```

Or when you want to write generic code that works on multiple attributes, while avoiding writing the same thing over and over:

```
for attr in ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]:
    print "%s is: %s" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr))
```

Comment: In that case you expect to somehow find out the name of the method during execution?